# Shortest way to generate a string from objects values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got an object :

```
var obj = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 32,
  c: 'foo'
}
```

I need to extract to following string:

```
'hello, 32, foo'
```

My current method is:

```
var ar = [];
for (var key in obj){
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    ar.push(obj[key]);
  }
}
var str = ar.join(', ');
```

Is there a shorter way than this?

ExtJs is allowed (jQuery can not be used).

Comment: If you don't write or include any code that extends `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties, then you can omit `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`, and have `for(var key in obj) ar.push(obj[key]);`

Comment: Yes, hasOwnProperty could be removed for now but obj could be more complex objects in the future.

Comment: In that case, I'd say just roll your code into a function that accepts the object, and the desired join string, and returns the result. *(I don't know if there's anything already available in ExtJs.)*

Comment: Ok, I realize it was probably a stupid question ;) And the code is small enough.
Thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: @Guid The shortest I can think of:  Object.values(obj).join`, `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 32,
  c: 'foo'
}

var stringValues = `${Object.values(obj)}`
alert('The String Values are:',stringValues)
```

The String Values are: hello,32,foo